# How to fetch data from Http client API to bind on ajax jquery in ASP.NET Core

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-ajax

I am getting an error in my ASP.NET Core project; I am calling an API using a `HttpClient` in my controller, but I am not able to fetch data from an jQuery Ajax call based on id.

My controller:

```
[HttpGet("/GetCivilID")]
public async Task<IActionResult> getId(Users usr)
{
    var randid = GeneratePassword1();

    var randomNumberUrl = _config["API:Url"];
    var basic = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["API:UserName"] + ":" + _config["DemographyAPI:Password"]));
    var ClientName = _config["D:ClientName"];
    var ClientKey = _config["D:ClientKey"];
    var payLoad = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    payLoad.Add("CivilID", usr.CivilId);
    payLoad.Add("ReferenceID", randid); //"20221129092059133"

    var jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payLoad);
    var content = new StringContent(jsonObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, 
   "application/json");

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {basic}");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ClientName", ClientName);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ClientKey", ClientKey);

        var response = await client.PostAsync(randomNumberUrl, content);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // var dict =
```

JObject.Parse(res.ToString()).SelectToken("Response").ToObject<Dictionary<string,object>>();

```
            //var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, 
    UsersBM>>(res)

            var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);

            return Json(dictionary);
        } 
   }
}
```

My view with the jQuery:

```
      $("#Ids").keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            alert("enter");
    
            $.ajax({
                url: "/GetCivilID",
                type: "GET",
                data: { CivilId : $("#CivilIds").val()},

                dataType: "json",
                processData: true,
                success: function (data, status) {
                    debugger;
                     
   //console.log(dataResponse.Header.Payload.ResponseMessage.Details.LATIN_NAME1);
                    console.log("data :" + data);

                    alert(data);
                    
                    //data = 
            Full.Response.Header.Payload.ResponseMessage.Details.LATIN_NAME1);

                    //alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

My json File :

```
"Payload": {
        "ResponseCode": "200",
        "ResponseText": "SUCCESS",
        "ResponseFlag": "True",
        "ResponseMessage": {
            "id": "28407010728154",
            "Text": "Success",
            "Details": {
                "Id_NO": "284070105551",
      
                "LATIN_NAME1": "ALLIJAHAN",
                "LATIN_NAME2": "VEMPALLI",
                "LATIN_NAME3": "VEMPALLI",
                "LATIN_NAME4": "SAB"
            }
        },
```

Comment: `but I am not able to fetch data from an jQuery Ajax call based on id.`Which action is called in your ajax with url `/GetCivilID`?

Comment: It's action url sir use JSON example which getting data from that URL using http clients used any action name sir

Comment: Could please help me sir how to bind data into ajax @yiyi you

Comment: It looks like you will get `dictionary` data in ajax success,what do you mean `bind data into ajax`?